# How to remove a snap application (docker) completely

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt, haskell-snap-framework

I made the mistake of installing Docker via Snap... Once I realised that snap hadn't permissions to run in my working directory (on a different partition), I removed it. Now I can't use docker after I've installed it via apt-get.

Please help.

I've done `sudo snap remove docker` but when I `sudo apt install docker` and run via `docker`, I get `bash: /snap/bin/docker: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. This works for me.

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

```
sudo reboot
```

the point is to restart the instance or terminal.

I hope this method can help

Comment: `sudo snap remove docker --purge` was very helpful in my case to avoid making a snapshot during removal that was taking a very long time.

Answer (score 11):

The command you are looking for is:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

i.e it's `docker.io` not just `docker`

On Ubuntu, the package `docker` is described as a "System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 applications", which is probably not what you want!

Comment: Or `sudo apt install docker-ce` – for the difference see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45023363/4850949)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues. The snap installation restricts permissions see https://snapcraft.io/install/docker/ubuntu first bullet point - probably for good security reasons given docker can give unlimited root privileges...).

First, `sudo snap remove docker --purge` to get rid of it. (from @jorgeca's comment).

Second, following [the official installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

```
### remove any previously installed docker remnants
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc

### install ca-certificates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg

### install docker certs
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

### setup docker repo
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

### install docker
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

### test installation
sudo docker run hello-world
```

I also did the following - tests installation binding a volume not in $HOME. This will error out with a snap installation of docker saying the filesystem is read-only.

```
sudo mkdir /test
sudo docker run -v /test:/test hello-world
sudo rmdir /test
```

Answer (score 5):

I did the same and just restarting the instance fixed it.

Comment: Or even just restarting the terminal does it.

Comment: @MWMillar Exactly. It is purely an issue with caching of executable locations - a very generic issue in bash not specific to docker, where executables are not in the directory whether they were previously found (although still in PATH). I added an answer with some more detail.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is simply that your `bash` shell caches the locations of known executables, in order to avoid having to scan through your executables search path (that is, the directories listed in `$PATH`) every time you type a command. Because you have removed the executable from one directory (`/snap/bin`) and added it to another directory (`/usr/bin`), this cache is now out of date. This means that it will look in the wrong location if you try to invoke the executable simply by typing `docker` rather than its full path.

It is possible to fix it simply by starting a new `bash` shell, for example open a new terminal window and type the command in there.

Alternatively if you wish to refresh the cache in the terminal session that you are already using, type:

```
hash -r
```

It is not necessary to restart your computer (although this would also work).