# Docker build "path . not found"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to make my first docker container

I installed dokcer-ce, following docker tutorial for ubuntu.

I create a folder and put my Dockerfile in it.

```
FROM docker/whalesay

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y figlet fortune && rm /var/apt/*

CMD figlet "Hy SUPINFO" | cowsay -n && /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

In this folder I made a :

```
sudo docker build -t whalesupinfo .
```

I always have this output

```
unable to prepare context: path "." not found
```

EDIT: I was in sshd, not working into it ?!

Comment: Have you checked if your case is something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511604/docker-unable-to-prepare-context-unable-to-evaluate-symlinks-in-dockerfile-pat)?

Comment: check again that your `Dockerfile` really exists in the path you are running the command

Comment: Please run `sudo -s`, then `pwd` and `ls -al`, and update your question with the full output of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double check that the Dockerfile is spelled correctly on disk, and that when you run `docker build`, that the Dockerfile is in the same directory that you're in.

If that still doesn't work, tell docker exactly where the Dockerfile is with the `-f` argument.

`docker build -t whalesupinfo -f /path/to/Dockerfile .`

I would also try running `docker` without `sudo`.

Answer (score -1):

sudo docker build -t whalesupinfo .
specify the dockerfile path
sudo docker build -t /Your /dockerfile/ path/ -t whalesupinfo .