# unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu, snappy

I installed docker on Ubuntu with `snap` (snappy?), and then I ran this:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/snap /usr/local/bin/docker
```

when I run `docker build` I get:

> ```
> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or
> ```
>
> directory

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511604/docker-unable-to-prepare-context-unable-to-evaluate-symlinks-in-dockerfile-pat

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this same problem. I was setting up an Ubuntu server and elected to have Docker installed during the initial setup. It installed using snap, and as a result I couldn't run Docker in any directory outside of my home directory. This includes trying to Docker run any program in `/var/`. I fixed it by doing `sudo snap remove docker` and reinstalled using the official instructions in the Ubuntu docs:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: docker installed using the ubuntu server wizard at its installation, don't works. Your tip helped me. Thanks

Comment: Why is it like this? 2023 and the snap docker install still has this issue. Is it broken for everyone, or just some people?

Answer (score 10):

I've got the same error using Ubuntu, and I noticed that I had installed the wrong  Docker.
Instead of (docker - transitional package) install (docker.io - Linux container runtime)

```
apt install docker.io
```

Comment: This answer is helpful. I installed docker.io and then it works.

Answer (score 4):

I got this exact error message when I was running in `/tmp/foo`.  When I switched the directory to `/home/me/tmp/foo`, The error went away.

Comment: I experienced the same issue here. I cloned a repository into `/opt/src` (Ubuntu 20.04). Since, I couldn't install Docker using the official methods, I tried `snap install docker` and it worked. 

I just want to confirm that running the `docker build .` in my home directotry DID work.

Answer (score 2):

Run docker cmd by root privilege, you can simply do it by using *sudo*

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall snap docker version

```
snap remove docker
```

then restart and install again using apt / apt-get

```
apt-get install docker
```

this will install all symlinks related

Answer (score 0):

doing

```
snap remove docker;
apt purge 'docker*';
apt install docker.io docker-compose-v2;
```

fixed it for me on Ubuntu 22.04