# unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in context path: EvalSymlinks: too many links error when installing libacvp on windows

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, cisco

I've been trying to use [cisco's libacvp](https://github.com/cisco/libacvp) on my windows (10, 64 bit) computer for some time now. I have installed OpenSSL 1.1.1g and Docker (19.03.12).

While trying to run `docker build -t libacvp_w_openssl111 .` in cmd I've been getting the error `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in context path: EvalSymlinks: too many links`.

I looked through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511604/docker-unable-to-prepare-context-unable-to-evaluate-symlinks-in-dockerfile-pat) (which seemed to get a lot of attention) but the only solution that was found there was to check that the `Dockerfile` was in the correct directory (also relative to the current directory from cmd), with no file extension and capitalized correctly, which it was. Beyond that - no help.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile, please? It looks like you're including directories out of current dir to build docker image.

Comment: @mulg0r It's [right here](https://github.com/cisco/libacvp/blob/master/docker/openssl_111/Dockerfile).

Comment: @mulg0r What exactly do you mean when you say I'm including directories out of current dir to build my docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you're executing `docker build` in a folder that has a lot of symlinks, some of them which are pointing out of current dir (unable to prepare context error message)

Try creating a new empty folder, copy Dockerfile there and execute again your `docker build -t libacvp_w_openssl111 .`

Comment: Interesting. Your solution did help me solve this problem (thanks!) but my folder was completely empty (besides a readme.txt file).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem but in my case it was a matter of long path where the Dockerfile was sitting. When I moved it to root folder of another drive it worked like a charm.